# jQuery show.bs.collapse event for nested Bootstrap collapsible buttons fires on more buttons than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nested

I'm using Bootstrap to make collapsible nested divs/buttons. I want to collapse all siblings of a div when it is expanded and to collapse all children of a div when it is collapsed (so that the expanded divs are from only one path from one of the root divs to an inner div).

I choose to do it with jQuery and not using Bootstrap's Accordion - just buttons with associated divs.

So I tried to select all divs that could expand and use the show.bs.collapse event, so that I would know which div was expanded.

```
$(function () {
  $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log ($(this).context.id);
  })
});
```

If my tree is like so:

- 1 - expanded

  - 2 - expanded

    - 3 - collapsed
  - 4 - collapsed
- 5 - collapsed
- 6 - collapsed

and I expand 3, I don't get:

```
3
```

but:

```
3
2
1
```

Why is show.bs.collapse applied to divs 1 and 2?

Comment: You can stop the event propagation by calling `event.stopPropagation()` inside the handler

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the tip. I added it, but I could no longer expand anything.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```js
$(function() {
  $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(e.target)) {
      snippet.log(this.id)
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1-1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne-1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1" href="#collapseOne-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1-1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne-1">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Collapsible Group Item #1-1
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo-1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1" href="#collapseTwo-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2-1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-1">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1-1-2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne-1-2">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1-2" href="#collapseOne-1-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                          Collapsible Group Item #1-1-2
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne-1-2">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Collapsible Group Item #1-1-2
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo-1-2">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1-2" href="#collapseTwo-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                          Collapsible Group Item #2-1-2
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-1-2">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Collapsible Group Item #2-1-2
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree-1-2">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1-2" href="#collapseThree-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-1-2">
                          Collapsible Group Item #3-1-2
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree-1-2">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Collapsible Group Item #3-1-2
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree-1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1-1" href="#collapseThree-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-1">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3-1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree-1">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Collapsible Group Item #3-1
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you! I wonder what exactly made the other divs react to the expansion of the first one, though.

Comment: I guess because "jQuery's event model can trigger an event by any name on an element, and it is propagated up the DOM tree to which that element belongs, if any". http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event

Comment: Wasted 2 hours before your answer. In the handler if (!$(this).is(e.target)) { return; } works. Thank you.

Comment: Works! This saved my day.

Comment: Can also use pure JS to compare objects: `if (!Object.is(this, e.target)) { return; }

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shown.bs.collapse` instead. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse_plugin.htm
section `The following table lists a few events that can be used with the collapse functionality.`

Comment: I tried that, but it still outputs the whole path of divs, all the way to the root. Also, I want other divs to start collapsing immediately after expansion of the div starts.

Comment: @NestedButtons Have you tried `$(body).on('shown.bs.collapse', '.collapse'`

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: body is not defined"

Comment: @NestedButtons meant `$('body')` or `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code -

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
       $(this).parent()
               .find("i.indicator")
               .toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
  });
```